# RotateAnimation : Listen to every Angle Change

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-animation

I have a `View` to which I have added a `RotateAnimation` and it is working perfectly. The only question that I have is that, is there a way to listen to every angle change. I know I can add an `AnimationListener` and use the following listeners,

```
rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

And also I can use `View.getRotation()` to get the angle of the view. But the functionality of the app changes w.r.t time calculated from the preferences selected by the user.

What I am looking for is a listener which can listen to every angle change.
Something like, `onRotateAngleChange(int currentAngle)`.
Any pointers on any such methods or any workaround that I can use would be a great help.

Regards.

EDIT : Final Hint/Code that worked.
Thanks to @yakobom for the pointer.

```
rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees){
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
            float degrees = fromDegrees + ((toDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);
            //Do what you want to do with your angle here.
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is implement `applyTransformation`, something like this:

```
    RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation (...) {
                 @Override
                 public void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)              
                 {
                      super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t); 

                       <your code here>
                 }
```

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate, from where I can get the real time angle? I mean `interpolatedTime` or `t` and how? I searched for it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Thank man it worked. I had to look into the Java code of Rotate Animation to understand what you meant. (Y).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add an update listener for `RotationAnimation` however you can achieve the same result by using an `ObjectAnimator`

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", initialValue, finalValue);
animator.setDuration(duration);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            currentRotation = valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("rotation");
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Alternatively if you're targeting API 19 or higher you can use the Animation apis in Kitkat added to make this much simpler as follows:

```
view.animate().rotationBy(finalValue - initalValue).setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            currentRotation = valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("rotation");
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, I added `Log.d("YO", valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("rotation").toString());` in the `//do domething` part but it was not logging values during the animation. Plus, do you know how I can fix one end of the view in ObjectAnimator, I was able to set pivot in RotateAnimation.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer but @yakobom 's answer was more to the point.